PIP yfinance is not loading
I have a problem with yfinance package in python. I installed using the following code:
!pip install yfinance

When I run it, it seems it is completed (see screen below):

However, when I run the following code I get an error message saying that the package is not found.
pip show yfinance


I have restarted kernels but still facing problems. Please let me know what is the error.

Try running 'xcode-select --install' in terminal.  I got my answer here

If you mean to import the yfinance package to your script, you can use import yfinance
